# Nexus 5 + TWRP: Booting to recovery works about 40% of the time

Tags: nexus-5, boot, twrp

I have a Nexus 5 with TWRP as my recovery.

I've encountered and issue over the past few months.

When I reboot to recovery from the OS, or from Fastboot, it'll stay at the boot screen a bit longer than usual, but then boot the OS as if I didn't try to get to recovery.  I can usually expect this 2-3 times and then it'll boot into recovery correctly like nothing happened.

It's been across multiple versions of TWRP and I've reflashed the current one a few times to ensure it wasn't something along those lines.

Booting to fastboot always works, it's just booting to recovery where I see this.

Comment: Try a different recovery. Also, what superuser app are you using?

Comment: Why would the superuser app (Phh) matter at all?

Comment: Because I have had some people have issues like this when not using an official superuser app (SuperSu). It all depends. I recommend you install a different recovery.

Comment: I need to ultimately use TWRP, so using another recovery would be for testing only, so that's not really a viable option.  Second, I said it ALSO happens when I boot to recovery from fastboot.  Considering I can do that with a completely zero'd out system and data partition, there's absolutely no way my superuser app of choice is the issue.  (Additionally, SuperSU is not reputable anymore, so nobody should really be using that)